# typescript argument can't use any in fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm facing problem where this line of code using fetch can't resolve typescript warning:

```
const fetcher = (...args: any) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());
```

putting `fetch(...args:any)` doesn't work? any clue?

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-meninsky-6zjzl?file=/src/App.tsx:55-363

Comment: Did you hover over the error to see the actual error? If so could you please edit it into your question?

Comment: fetch is built in method you cannot just put as many argument as you want inside...

Comment: Why not just type it? you can do it easily with the [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility type `const fetcher = (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) => `

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fetch requires at least one argument, `...` implies 0 or more.  0 < 1.  Just change it to:

```
fetcher = (arg: any, ...args: any) => fetch(arg, ...args)
```

Answer (score 6):

I had to tweak the answer from @dave a bit to build:

```js
const fetcher = (...args: Parameters<typeof fetch>) => 
    fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());
```